# Need label to stay near TextArea and position in the middle (but outside) of the Textarea

Tags: html

I want to make `<td><label> Reasons: </label><td>` to align in the middle of the `<texarea>` without making the textarea jumps away from the above mentioned `<label>`.

By using Chrome developer tool, i can see that there's padding for the Reason label; however, I tried remove padding from the label but the textarea still jumps away.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" stylesheet="text/css" href="../../css/style.css">`enter code here`
    <title>Absent Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <td class="move-left heading">
                    Royal University of Phnom Penh <br>
                    Department of Information Technology
                </td>
                <td class="move-right heading">
                    Kingdom of Cambodia <br>
                    Nation &nbsp; &nbsp; Religion &nbsp; &nbsp; King
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br> <br> <br>
                    <h1 id="title1">Absent Form</h1>
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>   
                <td>My name is
                    <input type="text" name="txt_name"/>. I am a 
                        <select>
                            <option value="freshmen">Freshmen</option>
                            <option value="sophomore">Sophomore</option>
                            <option value="junior">Junior</option>
                            <option value="senior">Senior</option>
                        </select> from class 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_class" maxlength="2" size="3"> of the Department of Information Technology of the Royal University of Phnom Penh. <br> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Georgia;font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">
                    Greetings, <br> Dean of the Department of Information Technology <br> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="objective" style="text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-style: double;">Objective:</label> An absent request for 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_num_day" maxlength="2" size="2"> day(s).
                    <input type="radio" name="first_session" value="first"> First Session
                    <input type="radio" name="first_session" value="second"> Second Session.
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="from">From: </label>Date
                    <input type="text" name="txt_fdate" maxlength="2" size="2"> Month
                    <input type="text" name="txt_fmonth" maxlength="2" size="2"> Year 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_fyear" maxlength="4" size="4">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td ><label for="to">To: &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>Date
                    <input type="text" name="txt_tdate" maxlength="2" size="2"> Month
                    <input type="text" name="txt_tmonth" maxlength="2" size="2"> Year 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_tyear" maxlength="4" size="4">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <table>
            <tr>    
                <td>
                    <label for="reason" style="text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-style: double;">Reason: </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="reason" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Tell us why you are absent."></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Due to reason mentioned above, I sincerely apology for this inconvenience. I hope you would understand and grant me the permission.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="move-right">Phnom Penh, Date
                    <input type="text" name="txt_sdate" maxlength="2" size="2"> Month 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_smonth" maxlength="2" size="2"> Year 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_syear" maxlength="4" size="4"> <br>
                    Name and Signature, <br> <br> <br> <br>
                    Name: <input type="text" name="txt_name1" size="40">
                </td>
            </tr>
                
            <tr>
                <td class="move-left"> &nbsp;Approved: &nbsp;Date 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_adate" maxlength="2" size="2"> Month
                    <input type="text" name="txt_amonth" maxlength="2" size="2"> Year 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_ayear" maxlength="4" size="4">
                    <br> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="txt_submit" value="Submit">
                    <br> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

CSS source code

body{
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
}

table{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 50px;
}

.heading{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Georgia;
}

.move-right{
    float: right;

}
.move-left{
    float: left;

}

label{
    font-weight: 600;
}

#title1{
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

input[type=submit]{
    font-size: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

The result that i want is the Reason Label to stay near TextArea and position in the middle (but outside) of the Textarea.

Comment: Here's another image that might give you a better look of my problem.
I tried removing padding, but it didn't work. :(
https://pasteboard.co/IrTVewB.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change table cell spacing attribute:

```html
<form>
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <td class="move-left heading">
                    Royal University of Phnom Penh <br>
                    Department of Information Technology
                </td>
                <td class="move-right heading">
                    Kingdom of Cambodia <br>
                    Nation &nbsp; &nbsp; Religion &nbsp; &nbsp; King
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br> <br> <br>
                    <h1 id="title1">Absent Form</h1>
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>   
                <td>My name is
                    <input type="text" name="txt_name"/>. I am a 
                        <select>
                            <option value="freshmen">Freshmen</option>
                            <option value="sophomore">Sophomore</option>
                            <option value="junior">Junior</option>
                            <option value="senior">Senior</option>
                        </select> from class 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_class" maxlength="2" size="3"> of the Department of Information Technology of the Royal University of Phnom Penh. <br> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Georgia;font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600; text-align: center;">
                    Greetings, <br> Dean of the Department of Information Technology <br> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="objective" style="text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-style: double;">Objective:</label> An absent request for 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_num_day" maxlength="2" size="2"> day(s).
                    <input type="radio" name="first_session" value="first"> First Session
                    <input type="radio" name="first_session" value="second"> Second Session.
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="from">From: </label>Date
                    <input type="text" name="txt_fdate" maxlength="2" size="2"> Month
                    <input type="text" name="txt_fmonth" maxlength="2" size="2"> Year 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_fyear" maxlength="4" size="4">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td ><label for="to">To: &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>Date
                    <input type="text" name="txt_tdate" maxlength="2" size="2"> Month
                    <input type="text" name="txt_tmonth" maxlength="2" size="2"> Year 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_tyear" maxlength="4" size="4">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <table cellspacing=0>
            <tr>    
                <td>
                    <label for="reason" style="text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-style: double;">Reason: </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="reason" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Tell us why you are absent."></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Due to reason mentioned above, I sincerely apology for this inconvenience. I hope you would understand and grant me the permission.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="move-right">Phnom Penh, Date
                    <input type="text" name="txt_sdate" maxlength="2" size="2"> Month 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_smonth" maxlength="2" size="2"> Year 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_syear" maxlength="4" size="4"> <br>
                    Name and Signature, <br> <br> <br> <br>
                    Name: <input type="text" name="txt_name1" size="40">
                </td>
            </tr>
                
            <tr>
                <td class="move-left"> &nbsp;Approved: &nbsp;Date 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_adate" maxlength="2" size="2"> Month
                    <input type="text" name="txt_amonth" maxlength="2" size="2"> Year 
                    <input type="text" name="txt_ayear" maxlength="4" size="4">
                    <br> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="txt_submit" value="Submit">
                    <br> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: That's a HTML attribute, not CSS.

Comment: Here's what i want to achieve. I tried your solution, but it didnt work
https://pasteboard.co/IrTRC8b.png

Comment: @borak there might be some parent CSS which could be creating this problem. Post the whole page if possible to see the real issue.

Comment: It works, but i only when i created another table and nested in the "main" table. I want do it without having to nest table inside a table. If that makes sense.

Comment: @borak, can you give a sample code for the same? can't check without whole code. But, I suspect, line justification CSS might be applied somewhere.

Comment: @DadyByte i have updated the full HTML code and also added the CSS code as well. Please check, thanks!

Comment: @borak, I still don't see the issue. Although, I have updated the snippet in the answer. Please check. If the issue still remains, check if any HTML body CSS in some other file might be changing alignment in your setup.

Comment: @DadyByte There's no styling in both HTML and the external CSS file and somehow it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0">

  <tr>
    <td style="margin: 2px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle; width: 1%; border: 1px solid #000;">
      <label for="reason" style="text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-style: double;">
        Reason:
      </label>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <textarea style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: -1px;" name="reason" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Tell us why you are absent.">          
      </textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply css

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: /* border: 1px solid black; */
    /* padding: 0px; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    padding: 9px;   ( for extra css in first td )

Comment: you can edit your answer to add more content instead of posting it as a comment

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.